# Implementing web socket channel on flutter and getting Bad state : stream has already been listened when calling the event again

Tags: flutter, bloc

I am facing the issue described above when I am calling the bloc after the app resumes from an inactive state, so that I get a fresh data stream from the websocket.

I have shared my code block with most of the instructions.

The problem is somewhere in subscription management of the websocket stream, I have tried a lot, but I am blocked at some point and couldn't proceed further

```
///Important///
///---packages needed
///web_socket_channel
///flutter_bloc
///---for multi bloc provider
///BlocProvider(create: (context) => SampleStreamBloc()),
///---reproduce the issue
///call the bloc with event as below from more than one screen
///context.read<SampleStreamBloc>().add(SampleStreamConnect());

import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:web_socket_channel/io.dart';

IOWebSocketChannel channelStocks = IOWebSocketChannel.connect(Uri.parse('wss://ws.eodhistoricaldata.com/ws/forex?api_token=demo'));

class SampleStreamBloc extends Bloc<SampleStreamEvent, SampleStreamState> {
  SampleStreamBloc() : super(SampleStreamInitial()) {
   
    //event for listening from socket
    on<SampleStreamConnect>((event, emit) async {
      emit(SampleStreamProgress());
      await emit.forEach(channelStocks.stream, onData: ((data) {
        Map<String, dynamic> message = jsonDecode(data);
        log(message.toString(), name: "Stream Response");
        if (message['message'] == "Authorized") {
          var data = jsonEncode({"action": "subscribe", "symbols": "EURUSD"});
          channelStocks.sink.add(data);
        }
        return SampleStreamSuccess();
      }), onError: (e, stackTrace) {
        log(e.toString(), error: e, stackTrace: stackTrace);
        return SampleStreamSuccess();
      });
    });
  }
}

//states
abstract class SampleStreamState {}

//events
abstract class SampleStreamEvent {}

//states implementation
class SampleStreamInitial extends SampleStreamState {}

class SampleStreamProgress extends SampleStreamState {}

class SampleStreamSuccess extends SampleStreamState {}

//events implementation
class SampleStreamConnect extends SampleStreamEvent {}
```

And shared the error too.

[image: Here is the image of stacktrace]

Comment: it means that you are calling `channelStocks.stream.listen` method somewhere else in your code (directly or indirectly)

Comment: no, but I am calling the bloc's `SampleStreamConnect` event again, because when the data stream stops for any reason till a certain duration, I need to reconnect to the same socket and the data needs to be emitted in the same bloc @pskink

Comment: If there is any other way to achieve what I described in a comment above, please suggest !